# onOptionsItemSelected() method don`t work in android

Tags: android, menuitem, android-menu

I want to open fragment, when clicked on menu item, but it`s not working and I don't know why.I tried to debug, but nothing help. If somebody can help, I'll be very glad. Thank in advance.

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.lineup.android.webbrowser.activities.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/clear_spinner"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_clear"
    android:orderInCategory="50"
    android:title="Clear"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="@string/menu"
    app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/downloads"
            android:title="@string/downloads"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_download"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/draw"
            android:title="@string/draw"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_paint"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/history"
            android:title="@string/history"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_clock"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:title="@string/settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"/>
    </menu>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" />
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.downloads:
            DownloadsFragment dlfrag = new DownloadsFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, dlfrag)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**DownloadsFragment.class**

```
public class DownloadsFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private ArrayList<String> listOfFiles=new ArrayList();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_downloads, container, false);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.downloads_toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Загрузки");
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()). getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_downloads);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter=new DownloadsAdapter(listOfFiles);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);`

you need to return your `view` here

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your answer

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate` method add `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

Comment: As I know, this method is for fragment.
I try to open fragment from activity

Comment: can you show a toast message or log on click on options menu?

Comment: I've added  picture with log in my answer

Comment: I didn't mean that, can you show a log message or toast message

Comment: Yes, I tried to show  toast, when click on this menuitem, it`s work ok

Comment: when you click does the text of toolbar changed?